# Separating multiple overlapping polygons using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, overlapping-features

How do I separate multiple overlays in a polygon using arcpy, according to image?

Each overlap must be a single polygon

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Our [self-assembling FAQ on using ArcPy with overlapping features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy+overlapping-features?sort=frequent) may give you some ideas for starting code.